# Proof relating equations of straight lines

Tags: analytic-geometry, area

Prove that the four points formed by the intersection of lines of the form $ax\pm by\pm c=0$ form a rhombus whose area is $\frac{2c^2}{|ab|}$

I found four lines as follows:

$ax+by+c=0\\
ax+by-c=0\\
ax-by+c=0\\
ax-by-c=0\\$

Now, what should I do next??

Comment: Next find the four points. Initially there are six choices of two of the four lines, but the first two and the last two are parallel so don't meet (unless $c=0,$ but that must be assumed in order to get four points).

Comment: You have asked many questions here in the last two days but have not accepted or (apparently) upvoted any answers. If you don't start doing those things you will not find people to answer your questions. Also, it is the way to show appreciation here. Upvote all helpful answers by clicking the up-arrow at the top left of the question. Accept the best answer by clicking the check-mark at the top left of the question. You may want to wait about a day after asking a question to accept the best answer, but don't wait longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first and second lines are clearly parallel, as are the third and fourth lines. So they do not define intersection points.

There are four other pairs of lines, each pair defining an intersection point. They are 1st-3rd, 1st-4th, 2nd-3rd, 2nd-4th. Solve each pair of equations by any method (substitution, elimination, Cramer's rule, etc.). That gives you the coordinates of the four points.

Your next step is to find the length of the sides, which will turn out to be equal. This shows that the figure is a rhombus. Or, you could show that the diagonals are perpendicular. Since we already know the figure is a parallelogram, this also shows it to be a rhombus.

Last, find the area of the figure. Do you know the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) for finding the area of a polygon defined by the coordinates of its vertices?

---

Note that, for the problem to make sense, that it must be true that $a\ne 0$, $b\ne 0$, and $c\ne 0$. Otherwise you do note get four points or a rhombus at all.